# jQuery in-place-editor to use jQuery autocomplete input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, edit-in-place

## Background

Creating a WYSIWYG editor that uses Dave Hauenstein's [edit-in-place](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/) and jQuery's [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) plug-in.

## Source Code

The code has the following parts: HTML, edit-in-place, and autocomplete.

### HTML

The HTML element that becomes an edit-in-place text field:

```
<span class="edit" id="edit">Edit item</span>
```

### Edit In Place

The JavaScript code that uses the edit-in-place plugin:

```
  $('#edit').editInPlace({
    url           : window.location.pathname,
    hover_class   : 'inplace_hover',
    params        : 'command=update-edit',
    element_id    : 'edit-ac',
    on_edit       : function() {
      return '';
    }
  });
```

The `on_edit` is custom code to call a function when the user clicks on the associated `span` element. The value returned is used to seed the text input field. In theory, the plugin should replace the `span` element in the DOM with an `input` element similar to:

```
<input type="text" id="edit-ac" />
```

### Autocomplete

The autcomplete code:

```
  $('#edit-ac').autocomplete({
    source    : URL_BASE + 'search.php',
    minLength : 2,
    delay     : 25
  });
```

## Problem

It seems that the timing for the autocomplete code is incorrect with respect to the timing for the edit-in-place code.

I think that the edit-in-place plugin needs to call the `autocomplete` code snippet *after* the `input` field has been added to the DOM.

## Question

How would you integrate the two plugins so that when a user clicks on the edit-in-place field that the autocomplete code provides autocomplete functionality on the DOM element added by edit-in-place?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Modify the jQuery in-place-editor source code by instructing the code to append an identifier onto the input field.

## jQuery in-place-editor Updates

This section details the updates required.

### Type Definition

Provide new attributes in the default settings:

```
  editor_id:    "inplace_id", // default ID for the editor input field
  on_create:    null, // function: called after the editor is created
```

### inputNameAndClass

Change the `inputNameAndClass` function to use the `editor_id` setting:

```
  /**
   * Returns the input name, class, and ID for the editor.
   */
  inputNameAndClass: function() {
    var result = ' name="inplace_value" class="inplace_field" ';

    // DJ: Append the ID to the editor input element.
    if( this.settings.editor_id ) {
      result += 'id="' + this.settings.editor_id + '" ';
    }

    return result;
  },
```

### replaceContentWithEditor

Change the `replaceContentWithEditor` function to call the create function:

```
  replaceContentWithEditor: function() {
    var buttons_html  = (this.settings.show_buttons) ? this.settings.save_button + ' ' + this.settings.cancel_button : '';
    var editorElement = this.createEditorElement(); // needs to happen before anything is replaced
    /* insert the new in place form after the element they click, then empty out the original element */
    this.dom.html('<form class="inplace_form" style="display: inline; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></form>')
      .find('form')
        .append(editorElement)
        .append(buttons_html);

    // DJ: The input editor is part of the DOM and can now be manipulated.
    if( this.settings.on_create ) {
      this.settings.on_create( editorElement );
    }
  },
```

## Autocomplete Coupling

The autocomplete functionality can now be activated the edit-in-place is revealed.

### Combined Call

The HTML snippet remains the same as before. The new call to `editInPlace` resembles:

```
  $('#edit').editInPlace({
    url           : window.location.pathname,
    hover_class   : 'inplace_hover',
    params        : 'command=update-edit',
    editor_id     : 'edit-ac',
    on_create     : function( editor ) {
      $('#edit-ac').autocomplete({
        source    : URL_BASE + 'search.php',
        minLength : 2,
        delay     : 25
      });
    },
    on_edit       : function() {
      return '';
    }
  });
```

This attaches the autocomplete function to the in-place-editor whenever the in-place-editor is activated.